# Putting multiple objects into an array in PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, .net, workflow-foundation-4

I made a web service with ASP.NET WorkFlow Foundation and I want to consume it with PHP.
I used *EasyWSDL2PHP* to generated the php reference file for calling the web service. Here is a sample of an *UpdateObject* method:

```
function UpdateObject($UpdateObject)
{
$int = $this->soapClient->UpdateObject($UpdateObject);
return $int;
}
```

So I can call this method with an `$UpdateObject` object which is defined in another place of the ref. file:

```
class UpdateObject{
var $objList;//ArrayOfObjectStore
var $by;//string
var $dt;//string
}
```

The `$objList` is a List of *ObjectStore* which I have defined in .NET. The ref class file has also describe it like this:

```
class ArrayOfObjectStore{
var $ObjectStore;//ObjectStore
}
```

And of course the ObjectStore is an object with some properties like this:

```
class ObjectStore{
var $category;//string
var $code;//string
var $create_by;//string
var $create_datetime;//dateTime
var $description;//string
var $modify_by;//string
var $modify_datetime;//dateTime
var $name;//string
}
```

For you reference, the signature of this method in .NET is :

```
Public Function UpdateObject(objList As List(Of ObjectStore),
         by As String, dt As String) As Integer
```

OK. I tried to call the web service by having one *ObjectStore* object in the list and it works good. However I don't know how to put more than one object into the list.

For your reference, here is how I make the call successfully with 1 object in the list:

```
 $test = new MyClass();

 $obj = new ObjectStore();
 $obj->category = 'test';
 $obj->code = 'test';
 $obj->description='test';
 $obj->modify_by='test';
 $obj->name='test';
 $obj->sys_abbr='test';
 $obj->sys_code='test';

 $objList = new ArrayOfObjectStore();
 $objList->ObjectStore = $obj;

 $updateObj = new UpdateObject();
 $updateObj->objList = $array;
 $updateObj->by = 'test';
 $updateObj->dt = '2014-2-22 22:22:22';

 $result = $test->UpdateObject($updateObj);

 echo $result;
```

How do I make multiple objects into the list? I have tried `array_push()`  and `$updateObj->objList->append()` but they both not working. Please give me some suggestion. Thank you for your help.

Comment: OK it's pretty simple I can use use `$updateObj->objList = array($obj,$obj2,...)`....

Comment: How can I make this question "answered" ?